# Hide Window Pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I Have Main Program and it's Open 3 windows with Buttons.
One from the windows is speed calibration I am really automatic logic after completion I want to close the window automatically from the function that implements the logic and does not succeed in any way I would be happy to help.

Here is the function In the main GUI that opens the speed calibration

```
    def Calib_window(self):  # This Function Open Calibration Window
    self.window3 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui_3 = Ui_SpeedCalibration(servicePort=self.comboBox_service.currentText(), 
                                    BarfPort=self.comboBox_barfield.currentText(),
                                    Serial_service=self.Serial_service, 
                                    BarfieldPort=self.Serial_pitot)
    self.ui_3.setupUi(self.window3) # We pass MainWindow for Bidirectional Variables
    self.window3.show()
```

Here is The main Function in the Second Gui: Calibration Speed

```
class Ui_SpeedCalibration(object):
    def __init__(self, servicePort=0, BarfPort=0, Serial_service=0, BarfieldPort=0):
        self.servicePort = servicePort
        self.BarfPort = BarfPort
        self.data = [0] * 20
        try:
            self.Serial_service = Serial_service
            self.BarfieldPort = BarfieldPort
        except:
            self.show_dialog_Error()

        self.help()


    def setupUi(self, SpeedCalibration):
        SpeedCalibration.setObjectName("SpeedCalibration")
        SpeedCalibration.resize(454, 526)
        SpeedCalibration.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SpeedCalibration)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_manualScreen = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_manualScreen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 351, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setUnderline(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        #################################################
        # This Part of The program Handle With Animation
        # create label
        self.label_animation = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_animation.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 280, 221, 201))
        self.label_animation.setObjectName("label_animation")
        # add label to main window
        SpeedCalibration.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        # set qmovie as label
        self.movie = QtGui.QMovie('loading.gif')
        self.label_animation.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        #################################################
        self.label_manualScreen.setFont(font)
        self.label_manualScreen.setObjectName("label_manualScreen")
        self.checkBox_burn_128 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_burn_128.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 231, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_burn_128.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_burn_128.setObjectName("checkBox_burn_128")
        self.label_step_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_1.setObjectName("label_step_1")
        self.label_step_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_2.setObjectName("label_step_2")
        self.checkBox_command_52 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_command_52.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 161, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_command_52.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_command_52.setObjectName("checkBox_command_52")
        self.label_step_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_3.setObjectName("label_step_3")
        self.checkBox_stab_52 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_stab_52.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 130, 361, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_stab_52.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_stab_52.setObjectName("checkBox_stab_52")
        self.label_step_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_4.setObjectName("label_step_4")
        self.checkBox_command_110 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_command_110.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 160, 161, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_command_110.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_command_110.setObjectName("checkBox_command_110")
        self.label_step_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_5.setObjectName("label_step_5")
        self.checkBox_stab_110 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_stab_110.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 371, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_stab_110.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_stab_110.setObjectName("checkBox_stab_110")
        self.label_step_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_6.setObjectName("label_step_6")
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 220, 241, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc.setObjectName("checkBox_shlomo_calc")
        self.label_step_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_step_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_step_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_step_7.setObjectName("label_step_7")
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 250, 241, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain.setObjectName("checkBox_burn_new_gain")
        SpeedCalibration.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SpeedCalibration)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SpeedCalibration.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SpeedCalibration)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SpeedCalibration)


    def retranslateUi(self, SpeedCalibration):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SpeedCalibration.setWindowTitle(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_manualScreen.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Speed calibration screen"))
        self.checkBox_burn_128.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Burn 128 to Gain and Offset"))
        self.label_step_1.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step1:"))
        self.label_step_2.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step2:"))
        self.checkBox_command_52.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Command 52 [Kts]"))
        self.label_step_3.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step3:"))
        self.checkBox_stab_52.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Wait to stabilization on 52 and read from Lumo"))
        self.label_step_4.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step4:"))
        self.checkBox_command_110.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Command 110 [Kts]"))
        self.label_step_5.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step5:"))
        self.checkBox_stab_110.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Wait to stabilization on 110 and read from Lumo"))
        self.label_step_6.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step6:"))
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Calculate new Gain and Offset"))
        self.label_step_7.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Step7:"))
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain.setText(_translate("SpeedCalibration", "Burn new Gain and Offset"))

    def main_calibration(self):
        # Step 1: Burn 128, 128
        self.Burn_gain_offset(gain=128, offset=128)
        self.Serial_service.close()
        self.checkBox_burn_128.setChecked(True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.Serial_service = serial.Serial(port=self.servicePort, baudrate=115200, timeout=0.)

        # Step 2.a: Up to 52[kts] wait to stabilization {STAB = 165}
        # Initialize
        self.dataPitot = [0] * 2
        self.Ctrl(speed=52)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.checkBox_command_52.setChecked(True)
        while self.dataPitot[1] != 165:
            self.Stabilization_Status()
            try:
                self.dataPitot[1] = int(self.dataPitot[1])
            except:
                self.dataPitot[1] = 0
            time.sleep(3)

        # Step 2.b: Read Speed from Lumo
        self.ReadWrite(67)
        Low_speed = int(float(self.data[15]))
        print('Low Speed = ', Low_speed)
        self.checkBox_stab_52.setChecked(True)

        # Step 3.a: Up to 110[kts] wait to stabilization {STAB = 165}
        # Initialize
        self.dataPitot = [0] * 2
        self.Ctrl(speed=110)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.checkBox_command_110.setChecked(True)
        while self.dataPitot[1] != 165:
            self.Stabilization_Status()
            try:
                self.dataPitot[1] = int(self.dataPitot[1])
            except:
                self.dataPitot[1] = 0
            time.sleep(3)

        # Step 3.b: Read Speed from Lumo
        self.Serial_service.close()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.Serial_service = serial.Serial(port=self.servicePort, baudrate=115200, timeout=0.)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.ReadWrite(67)
        High_speed = int(float(self.data[15]))
        print('High Speed = ', High_speed)
        self.checkBox_stab_110.setChecked(True)

        # Step 4:Vent & Calculate gain and offset
        self.Vent()
        gain, offset = self.shlomo_calculator(meas_low=Low_speed, meas_high=High_speed)
        self.checkBox_shlomo_calc.setChecked(True)

        # Step 5: Burn the New Gain and Offset and Finish the Program
        self.Serial_service.close()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.Serial_service = serial.Serial(port=self.servicePort, baudrate=115200, timeout=0.)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.Burn_gain_offset(gain=gain, offset=offset)
        print("The program has finished calibrating the speed of the Lumo!\n Remember to perform a speed test.")
        self.checkBox_burn_new_gain.setChecked(True)
        # Finaly Close Serial Connection
        self.Serial_service.close()
        self.BarfieldPort.close()
        # Trun off the Calibration screen
        ????????????????????????????????????????????????? # Here I want to Hide this window How
```

Comment: Do not edit the pyuic file, but use a multiple inheritance subclass (see [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)), so that you can call the window's methods like `self.hide()` or `self.close()`. Also note that you shall not use blocking functions like `time.sleep()`, so consider using the Qt serial classes or create a QThread for it (but use signals to access the GUI, do **not** try to directly access widgets from external threads).

Comment: Sorry but your code has too many problems, and "fixing it" even with some pseudo code would take too much as it would require us to almost rewrite it from scratch. Start by reading the link in my previous comment, and do some research on how to properly use QThread in PyQt (specifically when interacting with widgets, which requires using signals).

Comment: Thank you for try to help, I solved this problem as follow: `  def setupUi(self, SpeedCalibration):`
        `self.finsh = SpeedCalibration` after this line I can close the screen by: `self.finsh.close()` I don't understand why you say that my code has too many problems?

Comment: Reread my first comment, and consider that those aspects are of utmost importance and require rewriting most of your code (including the fact that the file generated from the UI has to be created again).